# Multi-language in params

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm using CodeIgniter framework I would like my urls to be like

http://localhost/myproject/en/

http://localhost/myproject/fr/

But as you know `en/` and `/fr` are interpreted as controllers.

How, by adding as `http://localhost/myproject/controller?lang=fr`, can I convert it to `http://localhost/myproject/lang/controller/`?

Comment: Try some of i18n libraries/code provided before. Although those are pretty old and provided for CI2, most of them could be adapted to CI3 with no much code change. Check [this one](https://github.com/keevitaja/mci-codeigniter) or [this one](http://jeromejaglale.com/doc/php/codeigniter_i18n).

Comment: Thanks, the second link seems to have what I need.